# Edit Cell in Pivot Mode AG Grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using AG Grid Entreprise,
When Pivot mode is active, the calculated cell cannot be edited !
Is there a solution for that ?

I need to implement a specific logic that triggers after editing a calculated cell in the grid.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.